# Restrict developers access on GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have two branches on m GitHub repository. I wanted to restrict developers access to these branches, basically I want Team A to access on Branch1 and Team B to access Branch2, and I (as admin) can merge master branch with both these branches when required.
Is this possible on Github so that TeamA and B can only access "branches" and not the "master" branch?

Comment: Restricting access to specific branches is not possible on GitHub.

Comment: Can you point me to some other option in GitHub with reference to my scenario?

Comment: Similar: [Restrict Github API access to only one repository of an user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30661125/55075)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by creating forks of the repository, one for each team. And you who is developer for the central repo can merge from both forks.

Comment: :"developer for the central repo can merge from both forks" Can I, the developer of central repository, push the latest changes of central repository to repositories (which are forked). I want the latest changes to be pushed to forked repository so that the forked repository can get updated with latest code in central repository, Is this possible?

Comment: sure - if you are developer on those you can do that.