# Restrict Github access to a single repository

Tags: git, github

I want to deploy software on a machine for a customer but have multiple private repositories and also belong to multiple organisations.

I do not want to give the customer access to all the organisations of which I am a member.  All I want to do is to deploy the code and allow the customer to update it periodically.

There is a similar question here: [Restrict Github API access to only one repository of an user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661125/restrict-github-api-access-to-only-one-repository-of-an-user)

However, I cannot seea way of restricting the SSH access to a single repository in Github.

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Does anyone know how I can allow access to a single private repository only on a remote PC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add him as a contributor to the project.

Open a new project (`fork`) where you want the customer to have access to and than add him as contributor.

He will not be able to see your original project but you will be able to see all his changes and he will be able to create pull requests for you.

### [image]

[image]

Comment: How can we do it through console for local git server?